# Connect to spark cluster using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Good morning ;
Please I have a question regarding accessing a spark cluster with python.
This is my first time installing and using spark , attached is the docker compose I used

```
\version: '2'

services:
spark:
image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.4
environment:
\- SPARK_MODE=master
\- SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_USER=spark
ports:

      - '8080:8080'

spark-worker:
image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.4
environment:
\- SPARK_MODE=worker
\- SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
\- SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
\- SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
\- SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
\- SPARK_USER=spark\
```

When I use the url http://my_server_ip:8080 I can see that it is installed correctly
[image: Spark interface]

but when i try to connect using python, attached my code

```
import os 
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import logging


def get_spark_context(app_name: str) -> SparkSession:
    """
    Helper to manage the `SparkContext` and keep all of our
    configuration params in one place. See below comments for details:
        |_ https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark/issues/18#issuecomment-700628676
        |_ https://github.com/leriel/pyspark-easy-start/blob/master/read_file.py
    """

    conf = SparkConf()

    conf.setAll(
        [
            (
                "spark.master",
                os.environ.get("SPARK_MASTER_URL", "spark://spark:7077"),
            ),
            ("spark.driver.host", os.environ.get("SPARK_DRIVER_HOST", "local[*]")),
            ("spark.submit.deployMode", "client"),
            ("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0"),
            ("spark.app.name", app_name),
        ]
    )

    return SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

I hade this error  :

```
/bin/python /home/spark-livy-on-airflow-workspace-master/src/main/python/livyondocker/main.py
23/07/18 14:36:39 WARN Utils: Your hostname, dataneo-hub-release resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 182.18.91.115 instead (on interface ens160)
23/07/18 14:36:39 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/07/18 14:36:40 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/07/18 14:36:41 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark-master:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:108)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark-master:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:284)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1257)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
        at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:516)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
23/07/18 14:37:01 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark-master:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:108)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark-master:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:284)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1257)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
        at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:516)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
23/07/18 14:37:21 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark-master:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:108)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark-master:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:284)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1257)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
        at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:516)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
23/07/18 14:37:41 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
23/07/18 14:37:41 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
23/07/18 14:37:42 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
```

any idea, can you help me please ?

I create a spark cluster and i try to connect it with python script

Comment: Where is this cluster based? is this on cloud? This seems like a networking problem to me. Have you checked the whitelist of the firewall?